# Visual Studio Code does not autocomplete javascript methods like padStart()

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

dom.js file:

```
let hour3 = '3';
var leadingZero = hour3.padStart(2, '0');
console.log(leadingZero);
```

vscode does not autocomplete padStart() method. Wondering if I am missing a configuration or an extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode go to Extensions tab and search for "@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features". Check if that feature is enable.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue in a .html file, but it works fine in a .js file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31794032)